# Acces to variable from another a class that extends activity to a class that extends view

Tags: java, android

in my code i want to get acces to the value of a variable in another class.
To be more precise I want to get acces to the vallue of the variable points in my class GameArena and overwrite the variable points in my class GameActivity with the value.
Here are the classes:

```
public class GameArena extends View {
int points;
public GameArena(Context context) {
    super(context);
    [...]
    points = 0;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);

  [...]

   invalidate();
}

public void actualizePoints(){

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    [...]
    points++;
}

}
```

And here is the the GameActivity:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

Boolean gameRunning = false;
int round = 0;
int points = 0;
float screenScale;
GameArena gameArena;
FrameLayout gameArenaFrameLayout;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    startGame();
}

public void startGame(){
    startRound();
}

public void startRound(){
    points = 0;
    startGameArena();
}

public void startGameArena(){
    gameArenaFrameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frameLayoutGameArena);
    Log.i("GameArenaFrameLayout", Integer.toString(gameArenaFrameLayout.getWidth()));
    gameArena = new GameArena(this);
    gameArenaFrameLayout.addView(gameArena);
}

public void actualizeScreen(){

}
```

}

Can someone give me a hint how I could solve this problem ?
Thank you.

Comment: Make a getter method for `points` in `GameArena`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a getter :

```
public class GameArena extends View {
    private int points;
    public GameArena(Context context) {
        super(context);
        [...]
        points = 0;
    }

    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }
}
```

In Activity :

```
gameArena.getPoints();
```

Comment: Wow that was easy, Thank you very much!